# Unable to create schema using hbm2ddl

Tags: hibernate, hbm2ddl

I am trying to generate schema using hibernate tool ant task.

Below is my ant task

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project name="GenerateDDL" basedir="." default="createddl">
<property name="src" location="src" />
<property name="bin" location="bin" />
<target name="createddl">

    <property name="lib" location="C:\eclipse\plugins\org.hibernate.eclipse.libs_3.4.0.v20120307-2104-H60-Beta1\lib" />
    <property name="vob.libs" location="C:/lib/java/jars" />
    <property name="jdbc.driver.name" value="${vob.libs}/postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar" />
    <unjar dest="config">
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />
        <patternset>
            <include name="**/*.class" />
        </patternset>
    </unjar>
    <path id="toolslib">
        <path location="${vob.libs}/hibernate-tools.jar" />
        <path location="${vob.libs}/hibernate3.jar" />
        <path location="${vob.libs}/freemarker.jar" />
        <path location="${jdbc.driver.name}" />
        <path location="${vob.libs}/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar" />
        <path location="${vob.libs}/hibernate-annotations.jar" />
        <path location="${vob.libs}/hibernate-entitymanager.jar" />
        <path location="${vob.libs}/ejb3-persistence.jar" />
        <path location="${vob.libs}/commons-logging.jar" />
        <path location="${vob.libs}/slf4j-jboss-logging.jar" />
        <path location="${vob.libs}/slf4j-api.jar" />
        <path location="${vob.libs}/dom4j.jar" />
        <path location="${vob.libs}/javassist.jar" />
        <path location="${vob.libs}/jboss-logging-spi.jar" />
    </path>

    <taskdef name="hibernatetool" classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask" classpathref="toolslib" />
    <mkdir dir="src/generated" />
    <mkdir dir="bin" />
    <hibernatetool destdir="src/generated">
        <classpath>
            <path location="config" />
        </classpath>
        <jpaconfiguration persistenceunit="myPersistenceUnit" />

        <hbm2ddl export="true" drop="true" outputfilename="ddl.sql" format="true" />

    </hibernatetool>
</target>
</project>
```

Here config directory contains all the class files including the class file for the entity classes.
When I run this ant task, I don't see any error as such but I don't see any schema being generated in the ddl.sql file also. I have tried to research this on the internet but didn't find any satisfying answers. I am not sure how to debug this further as I don't see any error messages on the console after running the ant task. Is there something obvious that I am missing in this ant task for it to generate the schema.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem to be related to persistence.xml. The persistence.xml in my project was referring to a data source. I need to have the complete persistence.xml in the classpath and no reference to data source as data source won't be loaded until the app is deployed to JBoss